# Simultaneously playing and recording video on blackberry smartphone

Tags: blackberry, video, record, playback

I intend to record and play video at the same time on my application. I am using BlackBerry JDE 5.0 and the Blackberry 9550 .
    I initialize two players, one to play media, and another one to record media. I used Manager.createPlayer(rtsp://server ip: port) to play video.

```
     String myEncoding = "encoding=video/3gpp&width=360&height=480&fps=6&vi​?deo_rate=16000&rate=8000";
        mRecordPlayer = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("cap​ture://video?" + myEncoding);
        mRecordPlayer.realize();
        _recordControl = (RecordControl)mRecordPlayer.getControl("RecordCon​trol");
        mRecordPlayer.start();
```

I  have recorded to a file .  but  the file always is  0  kB.    I do not believe this way  :createPlayer("capture://video?" + myEncoding)   can record video  from other player.   It  just  records video  from  camera.

```
 Is it possible to achieve the desired functionality with the API's exposed by RIM.
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could provide some pointer or help to solve the above mentioned problems.